# SetWindowPlacement doesn't restore to the same monitor when maximized

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I have a Windows Forms application which is persisting the location of a tool window with the following code:

```
ToolWindow = new ToolViewer(TransformedResult);

ToolWindow.FormClosed += (_1, _2) =>
{
    this.ToolWindowPlacement = WindowPlacement.GetPlacement(ToolWindow.Handle);

    this.ToolWindow = null;
};
ToolWindow.Show();
WindowPlacement.SetPlacement(ToolWindow.Handle, ToolWindowPlacement);
```

It works fine, unless the tool window is maximized.  If it is maximized, the window keeps showing up on my main monitor, rather than the one on which it was maximized when it was closed.

WindowPlacement.cs:

```
// from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidrickard/archive/2010/03/09/saving-window-size-and-location-in-wpf-and-winforms.aspx
static class WindowPlacement
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, [In] ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, out WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

    private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
    private const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;

    public static void SetPlacement(IntPtr windowHandle, WINDOWPLACEMENT placement)
    {
        if (placement.length == 0)
            return;

        placement.length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT));
        placement.flags = 0;
        placement.showCmd = (placement.showCmd == SW_SHOWMINIMIZED ? SW_SHOWNORMAL : placement.showCmd);
        SetWindowPlacement(windowHandle, ref placement);
    }

    public static WINDOWPLACEMENT GetPlacement(IntPtr windowHandle)
    {
        WINDOWPLACEMENT placement = new WINDOWPLACEMENT();
        GetWindowPlacement(windowHandle, out placement);

        return placement;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasons beyond my knowledge, I had to remove the default `WindowState` of `Maximized` which was set for the form in order to get `SetWindowPlacement` to restore maximized windows to the correct monitor.

[image: showing WindowState property of Window to be <code>Normal</code> in a working example, and <code>Maximized</code> in a not working example]

Comment: Although your answer is almost 9 years old, it is still relevant. I still have this problem. Could you tell how to set the WindowState to Normal in C#, instead of using the properties? Is it `placement.showCmd = SW_SHOWNORMAL`?

Comment: @ffonz, not sure.  You can see [what the different calls to `form.WindowState` do](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,df4518e8bef4a17c), which is using `ShowWindow(hWnd, SH_NORMAL)` instead of `ShowWindow(hWnd, SH_MAXIMIZE)` - but if that doesn't work, it may have something to do with the order of calling `ShowWindow` vs `SetWindowPlacement`

Comment: Put differently, you restore an arbitrary window position, you may have to call `ShowWindow(..., SH_NORMAL)` then `SetWindowPlacement(...)`.